# Parsing and adding content of a file in Python

Tags: python, parsing, sum

What I am doing is that I have a file which contains some data as follows:

```
ben     | 2 | 40
germany | 6 | 60
```

What I need as an output is::

```
ben     | 2 | 40
germany | 6 | 60

field 1 =   8
field 2 = 100
```

Please suggest me some solution to move ahead in Python.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Comment: Have you written any code to read the file and print it - giving the first two lines of your desired output?  If so, post that code.  If not, look at the Python documentation, such as http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/inputoutput.html.  After that, read about http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's probably a more elegant way to do this...

```
results = [0, 0]
with open("\path\to\file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        values = line.split("|")
        results[0] += int(values[1])
        results[1] += int(values[2])

print("field 1 = " + str(results[0]), "field 2 = " + str(results[1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

This has the aroma of a homework assignment to me, so I'm going to try to stick to providing some pointers rather than an outright solution.

You can use Python's `open()` function to open a file. The resulting object can be iterated over in a loop, like `for line in myfile:`. When you're done with the file you should call `myfile.close()`, and you could re-open it in "append" mode to write the answer at the end.

Each line will be a string, and you can call `line.split('|')` to get the line into chunks. I like to use multiple assignment: `name, col1, col2 = line.split('|')`. You will probably need to use `int()` to coerce the numbers from string format to integer format so that you can add them up.

I think that's probably a pretty reliable start, right?

Comment: I have already done what u have suggested above its just that i needed how to reach that field and then i use sum() to get my output. but nnow i have the answer. so will look after it and know my mistake.